# SharePoint Online : Converting Webpart as an Addin

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, sharepoint-addin, taxonomy, audience-targeting

We are trying to re-code our custom webparts into SharePoint Add-ins.  These custom webparts have properties that are Dropdowns , TaxonomyWebTaggingControls , AudienceEditor etc.,  How do we add these controls to Add-in Property? As far as we have checked, only basic types given below are available.

```
<Properties>  
<Property Name="" Type="string"  />  
<Property Name="" Type="boolean" />  
<Property Name="" Type="int" />  
<Property Name="" Type="enum" />
```

Any help or pointer is appreciated.